# Forward declaration with Inheritance and include | incomplete type or expected class name

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

Can somebody help?

Suppose, I have the following C++ files:

## Room.h

```cpp
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

#include "Console.h"

...

class Room {
public:
   void room();
};

#endif // ROOM_H
```

## Room.cpp

```cpp
#include "Room.h"

void Room::room() {
  Console::print();
}
```

## Console.h

```cpp
#ifndef CONSOLE_H
#define CONSOLE_H

#include "Room.h"
#include "RoomChild.h"

class Console {
public:
   static void print();
   static void printRoom(Room& room);
   static void printRoomChild(RoomChild& room);
};

#endif // CONSOLE_H
```

## Console.cpp

```cpp
#include "Console.h"

void Console::print() {
    ;
}

void Console::printRoom(Room& room) { 
    // print member of room 
}

void Console::printRoomChild(RoomChild& roomChild) { 
    // print member of roomChild 
}
```

## RoomChild.h

```cpp
#ifndef ROOM_CHILD_H
#define ROOM_CHILD_H

#include "Room.h"
#include "Console.h"

class RoomChild : public Room {
public:
    void roomChild();
};

#endif // ROOM_CHILD_H
```

## RoomChild.cpp

```cpp
#include "RoomChild.h"

void RoomChild::roomChild() {
    Console::print();
}
```

### My questions is

#### Is it possible to make it working?

I have tried to put forward declarations to each class or to some of them only. However, it does not work and give me either `... has incomplete type`, or `expected class-name before '{' token class RoomChild: public Room {`

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the class definitions.

Comment: You have cyclic includes, that can lead to all sorts of mysterious error messages. You can remove all includes in header files except for `#include "Room.h"` in `RoomChild.h`

Comment: After the removal in header, you need to add some in cpp file though.

Comment: Why do you have `#include "Console.h"` in `Room.h`?  `Room.h` does not depend on `Console.h`.

Comment: If you move `#include "Console.h"` from `Room.h` to `Room.cpp`, it will work. But be advised that `Room` and `room` are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The includes are all goofed up.

Delete the superfluous include directives from the files where they are irrelevant.

Add include directives on the files where they are depended upon.

**Room.h**

```
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H

/* DELETE: because Room.h does not depend on it.
#include "Console.h"
*/

// ...

class Room {
public:
   void room();
};

#endif // ROOM_H
```

**Room.cpp**

```
#include "Room.h"

/* ADD: because Room.cpp does depend on it. */
#include "Console.h"

void Room::room() {
  Console::print();
}
```

**Console.h**

```
#ifndef CONSOLE_H
#define CONSOLE_H

/* DELETE: because Console.h does not depend on them.
#include "Room.h"
#include "RoomChild.h"
*/

class Console {
public:
   static void print();
};

#endif // CONSOLE_H
```

**Console.cpp**

```
#include "Console.h"

void Console::print() {
    ;
}
```

**RoomChild.h**

```
#ifndef ROOM_CHILD_H
#define ROOM_CHILD_H

#include "Room.h"
/* DELETE: because RoomChild.h does not depend on it
#include "Console.h"
*/

class RoomChild : public Room {
public:
    void roomChild();
};

#endif // ROOM_CHILD_H
```

**RoomChild.cpp**

```
#include "RoomChild.h"
/* ADD: because RoomChild.cpp does depend on it. */
#include "Console.h"

void RoomChild::roomChild() {
    Console::print();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if console would depend on Room and RoomChild as in edited question?

Comment: It work even if it depend on it!!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH